# How to fix Hard disk unmount error

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, hardware, insufficient-memory, disk-drive

I tried to format a hard disk which was already formatted and i am getting this below unmounted error . Please tell me how to fix this error

```
sm list-volumes|grep public
public:8,1 unmounted 91da13ff-87b5-41bf-bf84-6300daae0cad
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a question about Android?

Comment: the uuid indicates ext4 file system, but android uses vfat/sdcardfs file system for public secondary external storage. try to format exFAT from PC instead

Comment: Why are you trying to do a trivial thing with an OS not designed to do such trivial things by end users? Just put your hard drive in a PC running GNU Linux, Windows or whatever you use and format it there. Problem solved! Or, get root access on your device and use busybox tools to format the drive and mount it from there.